# Merging two files by a column and add 0 when entry is missing

Tags: command-line

I have two files as below.

- File1
  There are five countries in File1

```
    >USA
    >England
    >France
    >Japan
    >Thailand
```

- File2
  There are only four in File2

```
    >USA
    >England
    >Japan
    >Thailand
```

I use `paste -d "," file1.txt file2.txt1` to merge the two files together

- output

```
    >USA ,>USA
    >England,>England
    >France,>Japan
    >Japan,>Thailand
    >Thailand,
```

As you can see here, the order of the list from the two files for the output doesn't align with each other because one value is missing in File2 -France. Instead, it shifts and changes after "France."

-Desire output

```
    >USA       >USA
    >England   >England
    >France    >0 (or any symbols)
    >Japan     >Japan
    >Thailand  >Thailand
```

How can I write a UNIX command statement that merges two files together and replaces 0 for the missing values,but the remaining orders stay matched? What need to be added, changed, or modified for the `paste -d "," file1.txt file2.txt1`

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: clear use case for a scripting language with a dictionary type. Try Python, or if you like that better, `awk`. `paste` itself can't do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said "any symbol" will do, diff might be sufficient:

```
diff -w -y file1 fiel2

    >USA                                >USA
    >England                            >England
    >France                           <
    >Japan                              >Japan
    >Thailand                           >Thailand
```

Missing lines are indicated by `>` or `<` indicating that a line appears in file2 or 1, respectively. `-w` will ignore spaces during comparison.

Comment: Thank you FelixJN

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}
{if ($1 in a) print a[$1],$1; else print $1 ,">0"}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thank you, Prabhjot Singh

Comment: @Bugger You're welcome.